# arma confusion in R

Tags: r, arima, state-space-models

Say I've got some AR(1) data from the model $x_t = .9 x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$:

```
dta <- arima.sim(model = list(ar=.9), n = 1000)
```

I can instantiate an `Arima` object with a call to `arima()`

```
wat <- arima(fixed=c(.9,0), dta, order = c(1,0,0))
wat$model
```

and verify that it correctly specifies the [corresponding state space model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/307129/8336). I can do the same with `makeARIMA()`:

```
m <- makeARIMA(phi = .9, theta = numeric(), Delta = numeric())
m
```

Both look good.

---

Q1: what's going on with the (log? negative? scaled?) "likelihood", though? It says in the documentation that

> For KalmanLike, a list with components Lik (the log-likelihood less
> some constants) and s2, the estimate of [kappa]

but I have to make it negative and scale it by the data length to look like `arima()`s log-likelihood. It is also shifted by "some constants."

Has this confusion been documented anywhere else?

[image]

```
phis <- seq(-.99, .99, .01)
loglike <- function(phi){
  m <- makeARIMA(phi = phi, theta = numeric(), Delta = numeric())
  -KalmanLike(dta, mod = m)$Lik
}
loglike2 <- function(phi){
  arima(fixed=c(phi,0), dta, order = c(1,0,0))$loglik/length(dta)
}
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(phis, sapply(phis, loglike), type = "l")
plot(phis, sapply(phis, loglike2), type = "l")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

---

Q2: How can I specify the variance term, $\text{Var}(\epsilon_t)$? It says in the documentation that

> The likelihood is a profile likelihood after estimation of [kappa]

How is it estimated? How can I fix it myself?